# SAMBA creating shared folders inside shared folder

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba, directory

I want to create multiple shared folders with different access permissions inside the shared folder.

For example, I accessed my Server and created 2 shared folders, Projects and Documents.

Anyone can access the Documents folder, but only employees involved in a project can access the projects folder.

Everything is OK until this part.

The real question is this.

Access the worker projects folder in a project.

There are 3 different projects. I want to open different folders for each project in the project folder and only the employees working in that project will be able to access these folders.

For example, if I am working in project 1, I can access the projects folder, but I cannot access the other 2 folders.

I created 2 shared folders /media/samba share/projects/project1 and /media/samba share/projects/project2 but these shared folders do not appear inside the projects folder, each one appears as a different folder together with other folders.

I want to open multiple shared folders with different permissions inside a shared folder, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood clearly what you mean by 'open multiple shared folders ' but I suppose you mean that if user1 is working on project1, he should have access rights to folder 'project1' and to all other project having other subfolders.  I would use the unix groups for that.

1. Create a group and put all required users in that group:

> ```
>  sudo groupadd project1grp   
>  sudo usermod -a -G project1grp username1
> ```

2. Define access rights on a group basis in samba ie, for each subdirectory, create a share with appropriate access rights in smb.conf

   > ```
   >  [Project1share]
   >       writeable = yes
   >       comment = all files for project1
   >       force group = project1grp
   >       force create mode = 770
   >       force directory mode = 770
   >       write list = @project1grp
   >       path = /maindir/subdirproject1
   >       valid users = @project1grp
   > ```